# Cancel Shipment Creation Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipment

How to Cancel Shipment Creation for an Order in Magento2?

I have a condition where If the condition is false I need to stop Shipment Creation and Cancel the order. How can I manage this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which condition you want to apply?

Comment: Hi mitesh, we have an attribute which says ready to ship or not, i need to check that attribute and cancel the shipment if attribute return false.

Comment: That means you want to hide ship button. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, you have to work on `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment::register()` .

Create a [**plugin**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)  on `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment::register(`

Then using around plugin on `register()`  implement your logic.

Create `di.xml` at your module and defined the plugin class of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Devbera_PreventInvoice_Plugin_Magento_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment" sortOrder="10" type="{Vendorname}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And after that create a plugin class on `app\code\{Vendorname}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment.php`,prevent the shipment create or cancel order or etc.

But note if you created any invoice of that order then you cannot cancel that order and you have to create a credit memo instead of cancel.

Comment: hi Amit, thank you for your response.I need to stop the shipment creation, which method i need to use to stop the shipment.

Comment: OOPS, it  did the mistake give the answer on invoice

Comment: The answer is update based  on Shipment